Can't share my entire screen on Ubuntu 22.04 on both Edge and Chrome
I can't share my entire screen on Google Meet. Only one tab can be shared.
I have tried uncomment this line: WaylandEnable=false using this command:
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf .
Now it shows like this:

